# Sending a response out from a Camel route

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, mule

Is it possible to send a response out from a route flow. For Example, in this below route, I would always like to send out a string response say, "hi" whenever the request comes from the uri mentioned..

```
<route>
  <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888/camelServlet/abc?" />

</route>
```

if possible, how do I do it?

I would like to use this route as a "run-check". To know if my camel route application is up and running or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Camel, there is something called [Exchange Pattern](http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html).

A sychronous request, such as the one you describe, is InOut and a one way request is InOnly.

Simply setting the payload will have Camel reply back with that payload. Like this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888/camelServlet/abc" />
  <transform><simple>hi</simple></transform>
</route>
```